# How to use lombok with default constructor

Tags: java, builder, lombok

My AssignedPropertiesDTO class is:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AssignedPropertiesDTO {
    @JsonProperty("hotel_id")
    private Long hotelId;

    @JsonProperty("oyo_id")
    private String oyoId;

    @JsonProperty("drn")
    private Integer dsrn;

    @JsonProperty("is_sold_out")
    private Boolean isSoldOut;

    @JsonProperty("is_purged")
    private Boolean isPurged;

    AssignedPropertiesDTO() {
        this.isSoldOut = false;
        this.isPurged = false;
    }
}
```

I need to set isSoldOut and isPurged to false. That is why i have made default constructor.
But i am using Builder() for setting class fields and somewhere just setting properties using getter/setter.

```java
AssignedPropertiesDTO matchingObject = assignedPropertiesDTOS.stream()
    .filter(assignedPropertiesDTO -> assignedPropertiesDTO.getHotelId().equals(Long.valueOf(entry.getKey())))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);

if (matchingObject == null) {
    assignedPropertiesDTOS.add(AssignedPropertiesDTO
        .builder()
        .hotelId(Long.valueOf(entry.getKey()))
        .dsrn(count)
        .build()
    );
} else {
    matchingObject.setDsrn(count);
}
```

My requirement is to set Ispurged/IsSoldOut to either True/False But not NULL.

```json
[
    {
        "hotel_id": 45693,
        "oyo_id": "GOA2161",
        "drn": null,
        "is_sold_out": null,
        "is_purged": null
    },
    {
        "hotel_id": 45693,
        "oyo_id": "GOA2161",
        "drn": null,
        "is_sold_out": true,
        "is_purged": false
    }
]
```

Please guide me how can i do this.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the booleans with default values? It's worth noting that booleans default value is false. Also, use a boolean not a Boolean so that it can't support null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Builder` makes an all-args constructor for you; it does not know about the non-default values required for isSoldOut and isPurged. You can use the `@Builder.Default` feature for this: `@Builder.Default private Boolean isSoldOut = false;` for example.

Alternatively just make them lowercase b boolean and 'false' is now the natural default. If that's an option at all, it's by far the best solution here.

Your final option is to make the all-args constructor yourself.

Comment: @Builder.Default private Boolean isSoldOut = false;
This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you define `isPurged` and `isSoldOut` as `boolean` instead of as `Boolean` the variables become initialised as `false` by default (as per your constructor).

In case you need another initialisation, you can simply define it when declaring the variable, e.g. setting one to true, the other to false:

```
Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AssignedPropertiesDTO {

  @JsonProperty("is_sold_out")
  private boolean isSoldOut = true;

  @JsonProperty("is_purged")
  private boolean isPurged = false;
}
```

Comment: And I was wondering, why this question was still unanswered. Lucky me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried assigning the booleans with default values? It's worth noting that booleans default value is false. Also, use a boolean not a Boolean so that it can't support null.

On an unrelated note you don't usually give booleans names starting with 'is'. That is generally left for the accessor.

```java
@JsonProperty("sold_out")
private boolean soldOut;
```

Comment: After adding this, 
I am getting error for setSoldOut(isSoldeOut); to implement setSoldOut method.

Comment: Change sold_out to is_sold_out and variable to match